# Joining a UDP multicast through a server on the other side of the tunnel

Tags: networking, vpn, udp, multicast, point-to-point-protocol

I've drawn a diagram below to help with this question!

So a company published a multicast UDP feed (company A) and another company connects to it (Company B). I have a point-to-point tunnel to Company B.

How can I get our machine to join the multicast group Company A is publishing via company B's machine?

We can ping company B's machine just fine from the terminal if we do

```
ping 192.168.255.1
```

But given the Python script below, we are not getting any data back. My guess is because we are not routing packets from 192.168.255.2 (our machine) to 192.168.255.1 (company B's machine)

Any idea on how to do this in the best manner?

If so, how could we implement this?

Thanks so much in advance!

Diagram:
[image: Diagram UDP]

Here is the socket code I am using (Python):

```
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '233.xxx.xxx.xxx'
MCAST_PORT = 18000
host = '192.168.255.2'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((MCAST_GRP, MCAST_PORT))
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                     socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP) + socket.inet_aton(host))

while True:
    print sock.recv(1024)
```

Here is the config:

```
tunnel    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.255.2  P-t-P:192.168.255.2  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1476  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6872 (6.8 KB)  TX bytes:17522 (17.5 KB)
```